# CQL_TEXT in CSW doesn't work

Tags: geonetwork, cql-filter

I need to retrieve some data from CSW server running GeoNetwork. I'm using this query but it doesn't work:

```
http://serverurl/geonetwork/srv/en/csw?
REQUEST=GetRecords&
SERVICE=CSW&
VERSION=2.0.2&
OUTPUTSCHEMA=http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd&
constraint=AnyText+EqualTo+Africa&
constraintLanguage=CQL_TEXT&
constraint_language_version=1.1.0&
typeNames=csw:Record&
RESULTTYPE=hits
```

Always returns to me the whole metadata (instead of 0; that's what I expect because there aren't any resources with name 'Africa').

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for GeoNetwork, but a CSW compliant request should probably look more like the following:

```
http://serverurl/geonetwork/srv/en/csw?
REQUEST=GetRecords&
SERVICE=CSW&
VERSION=2.0.2&
namespace=xmlns(csw=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fcat%2Fcsw%2F2.0.2)&
OUTPUTSCHEMA=http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd&
constraintLanguage=CQL_TEXT&
constraint=csw:title LIKE 'Africa'&
typeNames=csw:Record&
RESULTTYPE=hits
```